# Sync Services Ado.net conflict resolution

Tags: c#, ado.net, syncservices

is it possible to solve conflicts on client side with sync services for ado.net?
for example, with Client Insert Server Insert, updating client's table id (on client side) , tks

Answer (score 0):

While on the server side you can do:

```
Partial Public Class NorthwindCacheServerSyncProvider
    Private Sub ApplyChangeFailedEvent(…) Handles Me.ApplyChangeFailed
        Dim clientChanges As DataTable = e.Conflict.ClientChange
        Dim serverChanges As DataTable = e.Conflict.ServerChange
        ' Code to resolve conflict 
           If (clientChanges.Rows(0)("ModifiedDate") > _
               serverChanges.Rows(0)("ModifiedDate") Then e.Action =                      ApplyAction.RetryWithForceWrite 
           End If
```

You cant do this on the client, but, you can intercept the applying changes event and take appropriate action, like this...

```
Partial Public Class NorthwindCacheClientSyncProvider
    Private Sub ApplyingChangesEvent(…) Handles Me.ApplyingChanges
        Dim clientChanges As DataSet = e.Changes
```